# Exetion Method FirstOrNew

Tags: c#

Я написал метод который возвращает первый элемент с List , а если List пустой то он создает новый List, я проверяю есть ли в List элементы с помощью foreach и потом если count больше нуля то сражу же возвращаю первый элемент, но мне нужен более оптимальное решение без использование foreach.

```
public static class Exetion
    {
         public static T FirstOrNew<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
            where T : new()
        {
            if (list == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Value can't be null");
            }

            var count = 0;

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                count++;
            }

            var c = list.First();

            if (count > 0)
            {
                return list.ElementAt(0);
            }

            return new T();
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Странная у вас задача. Зачем вы считаете `count`, если можно сразу написать `list.Count() > 0`? Идем дальше, зачем вам `count`, если можно написать вовсе `if (list.Any())`? В итоге вашу всю писанину можно написать одной строкой: `return list.Any() ? list.ElementAt(0) : new T();`.

Comment: Зачем делать то, что уже есть в самом List?

Comment: не имею право использовать method linq

Comment: Не поверите, но `ElementAt` - это LINQ

Comment: да и поэтому нужно более  оптимальное решение

Comment: Это не linq, а тернарный оператор. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если надо без LINQ и других наворотов, то можно сделать так:

```
public static T FirstOrNew<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list) where T : new()
{
    if (list == null) throw new ArgumentException("Value can't be null");
    var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();
    return enumerator.MoveNext() ? enumerator.Current : new T();
}
```

У `IEnumerable` можно запросить некий "перечислитель", который позволяет получить текущий объект, а также сдвинуть положение далее при помощи `MoveNext()`, который в свою очередь вернет `bool` значение, возможно передвижение или нет.

Ну логика получается довольно простой:

- Берем перечислитель.
- Пытаемся сдвинуть его на первый объект.
- Если это удалось (метод вернул нам `true`), то берем то, что находится там и возвращаем.
- Если нет, то отдаем новый объект.

Тесты:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 5 };
var result1 = list1.FirstOrNew(); //5

var list2 = new List<int>();
var result2 = list2.FirstOrNew(); //0
```

Сам пример: [тут](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WpSfNs).

Comment: На мой взгляд более приятное поведение FirstOrNew, это вернуть `New` для null а не бросить исключение.

Comment: @4per Я подправил логику без LINQ и циклов, как просили. Остальное уже пусть будет на совести автора вопроса)